# Gaining access to heap metadata of a process from within itself

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, glibc, libc

While I can write reasonable C code, my expertise is mainly with Java and so I apologize if this question makes no sense.

I am writing some code to help me do heap analysis. I'm doing this via instrumentation with LLVM. What I'm looking for is a way to access the heap metadata for a process from within itself. Is such a thing possible? I know that information about the heap is stored in many  `malloc_state` structs (`main_arena` for example). If I can gain access to `main_arena`, I can start enumerating the different arenas, heaps, bins, etc. As I understand, these variables are all defined statically and so they can't be accessed.

But is there some way of getting this information? For example, could I use `/proc/$pid/mem` to leak the information somehow?

Once I have this information, I want want to basically get information about all the different freelists. So I want, for every bin in each bin type, the number of chunks in the bin and their sizes. For fast, small, and tcache bins I know that I just need the index to figure out the size. I have looked at how these structures are implemented and how to iterate through them. So all I need is to gain access to these internal structures.

I have looked at `malloc_info` and that is my fallback, but I would also like to get information about `tcache` and I don't think that is included in `malloc_info`.

An option I have considered is to build a custom version of glibc has the `malloc_struct` variables declared non-statically. But from what I can see, it's not very straightforward to build your own custom glibc as you have to build the entire toolchain. I'm using clang so I would have to build LLVM from source against my custom glibc (at least this is what I've understood from researching this approach).

Comment: You should pull the source for `glibc`. Under the `malloc` subdir, you can examine all the source. In particular, look in `hooks.c`, there is a public [non-static] function: `void *__malloc_get_state(void)` that serializes a _lot_ of info from various substructs into a `struct malloc_save_state` pointer [that is alloc'ed internally--and thus, must be freed]. Since there is a restoral: `__malloc_set_state`, I presume the given struct has _everything_ one might care about (e.g. main arena, fastbins, binmap, bins, ...). `glibc` also has the various hook functions.

Comment: I believe that you can get what you want [and/or need], with the above and the other hooks. I've used the hooks before, and I think they're much more useful than trying to use `/proc/self/mem` [which just maps raw memory--not too useful]. _If_ you need to find something that is _not_ exported, you might have better luck parsing `readelf libc.so` output or using the ELF [or `bfd`] library to find symbols and combine/relocate with address of a public symbol (e.g. `malloc`) to find the correct address. If you need base address of a `.so` load, you might parse `/proc/self/maps`

Comment: @CraigEstey unfortunately `malloc_{get,set}_state` were removed quite some time ago in glibc 2.25. See [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/hooks.c.html#429).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Of, course ... They were useful. I'm at fedora `fc29` at home, glibc 2.28, but I was looking at an older (`fc22` glibc source). Just pulled for `fc29` and, yes, it's gone. It would have been useful for debug, but looks like it was to implement some sort of hack for `emacs` [per comments]. Still, the ELF has `main_arena` as a local symbol, so it might be possible to get the address of it via maps/bfd and scrape the necessary `struct` definitions from the glibc source to cobble something together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement recently, so I do think that being able to get to `main_arena` for a given process does have its value, one example being post-mortem memory usage analysis.

Using `dl_iterate_phdr` and `elf.h`, it's relatively straightforward to resolve `main_arena` based on the local symbol:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

// Ignored:
// - Non-x86_64 architectures
// - Resource and error handling
// - Style
static int cb(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
  if (strcmp(info->dlpi_name, "/lib64/libc.so.6") == 0) {
    int fd = open(info->dlpi_name, O_RDONLY);
    struct stat stat;
    fstat(fd, &stat);
    char *base = mmap(NULL, stat.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    Elf64_Ehdr *header = (Elf64_Ehdr *)base;
    Elf64_Shdr *secs = (Elf64_Shdr*)(base+header->e_shoff);
    for (unsigned secinx = 0; secinx < header->e_shnum; secinx++) {
      if (secs[secinx].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
        Elf64_Sym *symtab = (Elf64_Sym *)(base+secs[secinx].sh_offset);
        char *symnames = (char *)(base + secs[secs[secinx].sh_link].sh_offset);
        unsigned symcount = secs[secinx].sh_size/secs[secinx].sh_entsize;
        for (unsigned syminx = 0; syminx < symcount; syminx++) {
          if (strcmp(symnames+symtab[syminx].st_name, "main_arena") == 0) {
            void *mainarena = ((char *)info->dlpi_addr)+symtab[syminx].st_value;
            printf("main_arena found: %p\n", mainarena);
            raise(SIGTRAP);
            return 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  dl_iterate_phdr(cb, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

`dl_iterate_phdr` is used to get the base address of the mapped glibc. The mapping does not contain the symbol table needed (`.symtab`), so the library has to be mapped again. The final address is determined by the base address plus the symbol value.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff77f0700 (LWP 24834)]
main_arena found: 0x7ffff7baec60

Thread 1 "a.out" received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
raise (sig=5) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50    return ret;
(gdb) select 1
(gdb) print mainarena
$1 = (void *) 0x7ffff7baec60 <main_arena>
(gdb) print &main_arena
$3 = (struct malloc_state *) 0x7ffff7baec60 <main_arena>
```

The value matches that of `main_arena`, so the correct address was found.

There are other [ways](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287617301895) to get to `main_arena` without relying on the library itself. Walking the existing heap allows for discovering `main_arena`, for example, but that strategy is considerably less straightforward.

Of course, once you have `main_arena`, you need all internal type definitions to be able to inspect the data.

Comment: This is very useful -- I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @VivinPaliath Glad it helps! If the code works for you and answers your question, please consider accepting the answer as the best answer.

Comment: Let me try it out this weekend and I will absolutely accept it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing some code to help me do heap analysis.

What kind of heap analysis?

> I want want to basically get information about all the different freelists. So I want, for every bin in each bin type, the number of chunks in the bin and their sizes. For fast, small, and tcache bins I know that I just need the index to figure out the size.

This information *only* makes sense if you are planning to change the `malloc` implementation. It does *not* make sense to attempt to collect it if your goal is to analyze or improve heap usage by the *application*, so it sounds like you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

In addition, things like bin and tcache only make sense in a context of particular `malloc` implementation (TCMalloc and jemalloc would not have any bins).

For analysis of application heap usage, you may want to use TCmalloc, as it provides a *lot* of tools for [heap profiling](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html) and introspection.

Comment: I'm not really trying to improve heap usage by the application. I'm just collecting statistics about what the freelists look like after every free. I'm also targeting a specific `malloc` implementation -- so the one in glibc that does use bins and tcache. If that makes sense? Thank you for pointing me to TCMalloc. I will check that out.